# Grunt uglify javascript including third party components

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs

Maybe just a dumb question. I have a project which uses say jquery. I want to generate a production code file for my own code, and uses Grunt minimize and uglify to produce the final code.

My question is: does Grunt uglify change the reference to third party code at all in my code, or just leave them as is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after disabling the mangle in uglify, the problem is solved.
So to recap, when we build third party code into a separate js, we should not use mangle in uglify. Otherwise, the reference will be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use grunt-uglify to generate the min.js for my code and third party code, and then grunt-injector to include it in my index.html file.

Comment: I'll definitely try grunt-injector. Thanks for the suggestion.